# How can I get the user ID from mysql database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to have the ID of the current logged user. But I only manage to get the ID of all users

I've got this in my **model.php**

```
    public function listUsers() {
        $this->open();
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
```

I have this in my controller : **users.php**

```
<?php
class Users {

    private $model;
    public function loadModel($model) {
        $this->model=$model;
    }

    public function view() {
        global $users; 
        $users=$this->model->listUsers(); 
        require "../app/view/_templates/header.php";
        require "../app/view/listUsers.php";
        require "../app/view/_templates/footer.php";
    }
}
```

And on my page I have this :

```
<?php 
            global $users;
            foreach ($users as $user)
            echo $user["id"]; ?>
```

So it echo all users but not only the one logged. I've tried just "echo $user[id]" but doesnt work. $_SESSION["id"] doesnt work either

Any ideas ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the logged in user's ID saved in the `$_SESSION["id"]`?
You should have a if statement where you filter the user to the logged in ID if you only want the logged in user ID.

Example:

```
<?PHP
global $users;
foreach($users as $user) {
  if($_SESSION["id"] == $user["id"]) {
    echo $user["id"]
  }
}
```

Depending on the usage, you could also implement a WHERE statement in your SQL statement where you specify a user ID (example: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$userid'`).